# how to insert header file as first line into data file in HDFS without using getmerge(performance issue while copying to local)?

Tags: hadoop, merge, header, hdfs

I am trying to insert header.txt as first line into data.txt without using getmerge. Getmerge copies to local and inserts into third file. But I want in HDFS only

Header.txt

Head1,Head2,Head3

Data.txt

100,John,28

101,Gill,25

102,James,29

I want output in Data.txt file only like below :

Data.txt

Head1,Head2,Head3

100,John,28

101,Gill,25

102,James,29

Please suggest me whether can we implement in HDFS only ?

Answer (score 0):

HDFS supports a [`concat`](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java#L1416) (short for concatenate) operation in which two files are merged together into one without any data transfer. It will do exactly what you are looking for. Judging by the [file system shell guide documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html), it is not currently supported from the command line, so you will need to implement this in Java:

```
FileSystem fs = ...
Path data = new Path("Data.txt");
Path header = new Path("Header.txt");
Path dataWithHeader = new Path("DataWithHeader.txt");
fs.concat(dataWithHeader, header, data);
```

After this, `Data.txt` and `Header.txt` both cease to exist, replaced by `DataWithHeader.txt`.

Comment: The `getmerge` command does just this according to the linked doc (specifically [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge) )

Comment: @ataji, the `getmerge` command will read all of the data into a local file, then you would need to move that local file back onto HDFS. So, you've transferred the data all the way to your local machine and back just to merge it. `concat`, however, will perform this operation without any data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

I got other way like :

Hadoop fs  cat  hdfs_path/header.txt  hdfs_path/data.txt | Hadoop fs  -put  -  hdfs_path/Merged.txt

This is having drawback as cat command reads complete data which impacts performance.

Comment: Just a heads up for the future, if you want to reply to an answer, you should comment on the answer rather than creating a new answer.

Your solution makes sense if data volumes are very small, since it is simple and easy, but as you said won't work well with large data since all of the data is streamed through the local client. For large data, it is much better to use `concat` as described in my answer, since this involves no data transfer.